# Notepad++ double click select word include other non-word characters

Tags: notepad++, highlight, word-boundary

I've been using notepad++ for a long time. One functionality I use a lot is to double click a word to have itself and all appearances in the same file to be highlighted. But the recent update seems to change the word boundary definition. Specifically if there are leading or trailing tabs around the word, they all get highlighted (causing other appearances of the same word, but without tabs around them, to NOT be highlighted), and if there are closing parentheses after the word (but not opening paren), they also get selected.

I've played with Settings->Preferences->Delimiter to no avail because it only allow you to *add* characters as part of word, but what I want is to *subtract* tabs and parenthesis. What should I do? Thx.

Comment: What version are you using, and what version were you using before updating?

Comment: 32bit v7.3.3. It is possible that the change is due to some confounding factor other than version. How should I trouble shoot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After checking plugins and other possible configurations. I just closed and restarted the Notepad++ application and the original issue somehow went away. I'm leaving this answer here in case other users observe similar behavior.

Comment: After merely restarting it, somehow the issue went away. It seems that after the update, it was stuck with shared memory issues, restarting it made to reboot all memory thus solving the problem . . .

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again? :-D

Answer (score 1):

Per my testing with the latest N++ (7.3.3), there was no difference recently made in word boundary behavior in Notepad++. (If you think the opposite, please edit your question and describe exact cases where double clicking behaves differently.)

Try downloading the latest Minimalist Notepad++ version and test it. (There is a download link **Notepad++ minimalist package 32-bit x86** on title page of N++ homepage.)

If the latest N++ still behaves consistently with older versions, the problem is most likely caused by some installed N++ plugin (or by recently updated version of some plugin).

Comment: I merely closed and restarted the notepad++ and somehow the issue went away. Thx for your help to confirm there is no material change in version update though.

Comment: @Zhang18 – you could keep this answer as accepted because it helped you to solve your problem.